# Xamarin iOS - Set SDK location through command line

Tags: xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Seeing this error:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(266,3): error : Could not find a valid Xcode app bundle at '/Applications/Xcode.app'. Please update your Apple SDK location in Visual Studio's preferences (Projects > SDK Locations > Apple > Apple SDK).
```

Because we need to support different versions of Xcode, we have Xcode installed like `/Applications/Xcode.12.4.app`

We also don't have Visual Studio for Mac installed and installed the mono tools, along with [xamarin-macio](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios)s, directly.

How do we then set the SDK location because I can't open Visual Studio to go to preferences, because there is no Visual Studio?

Comment: XCode command line tools has "xcode-select", or you could try using a symbolic link

Comment: no xcode-select doesn't work. When my build start I do that, but and even using fastlane, but that doesn't work. The build tools still complain that Xcode can't be found.